# Passing data from Datatable to a function. Is 'CInt' needed?

Tags: vb.net, casting, datatable, integer

I extract data from a DB into a `DataTable`, then I need to pass some data (from the `DataTable`) to a function.

I've checked data type columns and some data are `Int16` other data are `Int32` and other are `Int64`.

Assuming that the function expects `integers`, is it a good pratice to use `CInt` on data from `DataTable` before pass them to the function or is unnecessary?

Comment: What if you need to pass a value from the Int64 column to the function and the value is bigger than Int32.MaxValue? Perhaps you need to change your function and accept a Int64 as input.

Comment: @Steve The Int64 value is a 'Count' column that I know can be max 100 but MySqlHelper returns Int64 type. Naturally I could change my function input. But what is the better choice?

Comment: In any case, unless you use Option Strict Off (which is bad bad bad),  you are forced to use CInt on the Int64 value if you want to pass it to a function that expects an integer

Comment: @Steve Yes, I'm bad: I'm using Option Strict Off. But code is only for myself and my logic is: 1st make code works; 2nd make code better. As soon as possible I'll be using Option Strict On ;)

Comment: Then you don't need the CInt unless you want it for clarity becase with Option Strict Off the automatic conversion between Int64 to Int32 is done by the compiler

Comment: @Steve Ok I already know this. I was asking for a better code: 1) use `CInt`? 2) change function input? 3) other? (If you post it as an answer I'm sure I'll accept it) Thanks for your help (also for past answers)

Comment: I would go for changing the function input. In your context you will never get an automatic conversion but I like to not have casting spread in my code. However this is a personal opinion. See you again on SO

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't involve a specific issue, rather a recommendation and or opinion. This would be better suited here at [**Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Personally, I would turn on Option Strict .. and - if it isn't - Option Explicit as well. They force you to write better code. ;) Oh and Option Infer Off